# Can I create a "Node JS" desktop application which runs without a web browser?

Tags: web-browser, node.js, desktop-environment

I want to create desktop application using "Node JS", can I run the program without a web browser? If Yes, how?

Comment: Yes, you can. On Stack Overflow there are various answers to the question ["Is it possible to create desktop applications with node.js?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8794140/is-it-possible-to-create-desktop-applications-with-node-js)

Answer (score 2):

node.js can be used to create a stand-alone desktop application.  It does not have to be used only to create a web server that would be used in concert with a browser.

For example, you could write a node.js program to search through a comma delimited text file, find a bunch of data, then insert that data into a database, then output to the console how many records were inserted.

node.js can run other programs, read/write files, make connections to other servers, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Yes and amazingly simple.

[image: Electron Logo]

You need the tool called [electron](http://electron.atom.io/) which is made by Github and is essentially chromium browser with tabs etc removed and a better desktop integration.

Here's an quick guide about running your apps though electron - http://electron.atom.io/docs/v0.28.0/tutorial/quick-start/

And for example of apps created through electron the most famous and arguably best is the Atom code editor by Github.

[image: Atom preview]

Electron was earlier called `atom-shell`.